# Slice querySelector but modify DOM on Submit()

Tags: javascript, dom, slice

The following is a validation script for radio inputs with help from this post: [Validating Multiple Radio Button Groups in Vanilla JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344260/validating-multiple-radio-button-groups-in-vanilla-js)

I now need to add a class to a radio input's parentNode after its been sliced.  Is this possible? The below code works here: https://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/aw0kvfm5/49/ but it needs an error class if it doesn't validate.  is there a way around the sliced array or do i need to perform yet another loop?

Edit to my original question:
How can i access only the element with hasUnanswered and not every single radio thats available.

Givin this code:

```
    function submit(event) {
      const radio_htm = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
      const radios_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(radio_htm);

      // Reduce to get an array of radio button sets
    const questions = Object.values(radios_array.reduce((result, el) => {
      return Object.assign(result, {[el.name]: (result[el.name] || []).concat(el)});
    }, {}));

    // Loop through each question, looking for any that aren't answered.
    const hasUnanswered = questions.some(question => {
      !question.some(el => {
        return el.checked;
      })
     });

    if (hasUnanswered) {
        radio_not_pass = false;
        // Retrieve DOM element from sliced array - radios_array and modify dom.
        // Suggestion works here.  
        // What about accessing only radios that = hasUnanswered
        radios.forEach(radio=>radio.parentNode.classList.add('error'))

    } else {
      radio_not_pass = true;

    }

    if (!radio_not_pass) {
     event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `.slice`?

Comment: @hev1 - im not familiar enough with slice on how to retrieve that sliced html element. can you elaborate?

Comment: What do you mean by retrieve? Just access the index in the array to get the element.

Comment: @hev1 - sorry but im not sure if i understand your suggestion. "index method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present." -  im not sure how this can help me since id like to find parentNode of 'hasUnanswered'

Comment: I meant using bracket notation to access the element at any index.

Comment: `radios_array.forEach(radio=>radio.parentNode.classList.add('my-class'))`

Comment: @hev1 - your suggestion seems to work to a degree that it access's my radio array but doesn't apply only to my invalid input.  Also, is your suggestion using your original idea of bracket notation and index?

Comment: I meant using bracket notation to retrieve a single element. If you need to add a class to every element's parent, you need a loop, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array contains all of the elements, so you can just loop over it and add the class to the parent of each element.

```
radios_array.forEach(radio=>radio.parentNode.classList.add('my-class'))
```

You can use `forEach` along with `some` to add the error class conditionally.

```
let hasUnanswered = false;
questions.forEach(question => {
  if(!question.some(el => {
    return el.checked;
  })){
    hasUnanswered = true;
    question.forEach(el => el.parentNode.classList.add('error'));
  } else {
    question.forEach(el => el.parentNode.classList.remove('error'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! could you take a look at my questions edit with your suggestion.

Comment: looks great. So simple